# Htaccess, mod_rewrite and regular expression for alphanumeric and dashes only

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Just can't figure aout those regular expressions.

I have an .htaccess file with some url rewrites. Look below what I have now:

```
RewriteRule ^news news/ [R]
RewriteRule ^news/([-A-z0-9]+)/$ news/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^news/([-A-z0-9]+)$ index.php?news=$1 [L]
```

I don't think this is correct, I mean I think it could be better.

This is what they have to do.

- If visitor visits
  www.mydomain.com/news or
  www.mydomain.com/news/ he shlould be
  redirected to
  www.mydomain.com/index.php
- If visitor visits
  www.mydomain.com/news/test-slug or
  www.mydomain.com/news/test-slug/ he
  shlould be redirected to
  www.mydomain.com/index.php?news=test-slug
- The slugs only contain letters (A-Z
  and a-z), numbers (0-9) and dashes
  "-", so I need a correct regex for
  this

Can someone help me to build the correct rewrites?

Answer (score 2):

You can summarize your first two rules with this rule:

```
 RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will remove the trailing slash from requests. And your third rule looks fine. Expect that the range `A`-`z` will not just contain the ranges `A`-`Z` (0x41-0x5A) and `a`-`z` (0x61-0x7A) but also the character between those two ranges `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `=` and `` `. I would use`[-A-Za-z0-9]` instead.

Comment: I changed my htaccess with these two rules you supplied:
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] and 
RewriteRule ^news/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?news=$1 [L]
 however when I go to mydomain.com/news, I get a 404 error..

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
RewriteRule ^/news(/)(.+)$ /index.php?news=$2 [L]
```